# CentOS Repo on RHEL 5.6?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

Does anyone know how to setup the CentOS repositories to work under RHEL 5.6? Please be specific if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Migration Guide"](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file called

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo
```

Have following in it

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://yum.theplanet.com/5.6/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://yum.theplanet.com/5.6/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
```

This might break things though!